# openWRT basic auth system

Tags: openwrt

I trying to implement a very basic auth system that will grant internet through a non-password router (TP Link TL-WR841ND) on a form post to a URL. The TP Link has openWRT installed.

I have searched around and have evaluated a few options such as chilli, coova-chilli, wifidog, but as far as I can understand they do require radius on an external server to perform auth which I would like to avoid since it's more complicated than what I am willing to take on.

I was wondering if it is possible to achieve this using iptables or traffic rules,

The desired flow:

1. Users connect to non-password wifi
2. Users try to access any url
3. Users get redirected to the router www/ where the html form live
4. Users post form to url [myauthservice.com] (only permitted ip)
5. Response is received from url [json, xml]
6. Router allow users to browse freely over the internet for its session

Any ideas, suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Nodogsplash?

The authentication part:
https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash#51-site-wide-username-and-password

Installation:
http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.nodogsplash
https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash#51-site-wide-username-and-password

Answer (score 0):

nodogsplash - can be captive portal user and password mode but cant be voucher and each user time limit internet access. sell voucher for  each user by time limit or data usage and more futures bandwidth limit, multiple login, time + bandwidth. any one can be recommended me. 
try wifidog